# How to deal with delay preventing multiple login/register try

Tags: forms, security, cookies

I want somehow to secure my login/register forms from multiple, invalid, login tries, or multiple user registrations (for example by robots). 
I'm setting some value in cookie session that tells server-side script to apply time delay, while processing request. Delay depends on number of tries and increases delay.
Is it the right way to do that thing? Note that forms won't work without cookie support enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The client can pass whatever cookies they want. The attacker can choose not to send the cookie that tells the server to be slow.

A common implementation of a *tar pit* is to store attempts by IP address (they can't spoof IP addresses with TCP because it's connection based, not connectionless). If the failed attempts is over a threshold, then slow it down (a simple pause/sleep will do), but don't progressively get slower.

The idea is that legitimate users from the same shared IP address won't be greatly affected if it's slow for them just once (since they'll most likely successfully login the first time), but automated attacks become difficult because it slows them down significantly. Try something like 5 seconds.